# MySQL query with left Join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:
Items:

```
| Item|
   A
   B
   C
```

userItems:

```
| UID |  Item
   1      A
   1      C
```

This loop shows the data from table Items:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Items`ORDER by `Icons` ASC"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {
    echo $row['Item'];
    echo "Unlock";
    }
```

Basically I need to display Unlocked instead of Unlock if the user with UID = $uid has the item.

This query gets the user items:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userItems` WHERE `UID` = '$uid'");
```

I believe the solution is an left join, but I don't know how to do it. How can I make it work?

Comment: Why do you query from `Items` table at all? You have `Item` column in `userItems` as well.

Comment: I could insert all items to `userItems` on registration and add another column but it's easier to have a different table in case I want to add new items in the future.

Comment: @zerkms I think there's more in the `Items` table than a single column, `Icons` for example

Comment: @Phil: then it is bad example ;-) programmers solve troubles, not make predictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Items.*, useritems.UID FROM `Items` 
    left join useritems on Items.Item=useritems.Item 
    ORDER by `Icons` ASC
```

Then just use logic in your PHP to display Unlocked when user $row["items.UID"] equals $uid

Comment: I'd change the `*` to `Items.*, userItems.UID`. Just can't abide by a single `*` with joined tables. Who knows what you're going to get back

Comment: You're right.  I have no idea what might be lurking in those tables. ;)

Comment: @Liso22 You're kidding! I haven't done SQL in months.  I thought for sure I'd have a syntax error or detail lost in there somewhere.